# What does -XDignore.symbol.file do as a compiler option in IntelliJ 2020.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, javac

I just upgraded from IntelliJ 2019.3 to 2020.1 and it is having various problems, mainly it is not highlighting errors in the code and it is also not doing syntactic highlighting correct either. I found this compiler flag that I don't remember being there and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about it either. Does anybody know what this is doing?

[image: Compiler Options img]

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) says it is some kind of non-standard option, but I don't see anything resembling -XD, and most options like this seem like there should be an equals sign and a value included.

Answer (score 0):

The com.sun stuff, part of rt.jar, is meant for internal usage, and can change (be dropped etc.) even along minor JDK version changes. For example javac is not willing to honor "import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.annotation.OverrideAnnotationOf" and the compilation fails.

Except with the -XDignore.symbol.file option. Then the above import works. (The cited example is with javac 1.8.0_371).